# Disable module in child theme or specific store in magento 2.3

Tags: magento2

How can disable module in particular store or child theme, before magento 2.2 version there is advanced option for disable the module store vise in admin. I am working with 2.3 there is no option to disable the module via admin. can you suggest me how can disable module as particular theme or store.

Answer (score 0):

Module status is no longer stored in XML, it is stored in app/etc/config.php, so there is no way to disable the module in a child theme or for a particular view. Module status is system wide, so it is either totally enabled or totally disabled for all themes/stores.